# How to do knockout text effect in canva?

Tags: text, font-design, canva

How to do knockout text effect in canva? I've tried to search for a tutorial in youtube but was unable to find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by knockout text effect? Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Canva but a quick search shows there's some rudimentary form of it using what appears to be shapes. Type in "Photoholder" and you'll get some options. Scroll down and you can find there are letters and numbers to use.

Here is a video tutorial I found that may be helpful to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Y1eJ5Ll8SM

For the record Knockout Text is most commonly done using Clipping Masks which is how I was able to find the tutorial.